# Computed field result in odoo 10

Tags: odoo

I am working on student registration module. I want to to auto generate registration code and save it into database where as computed method having some issue.
1.. can't save Computed result in database.
2.. when i use store attribute with field and depends api then there is not increment in variable.

here is my code below.

```py
reg_code = fields.Char(compute='code', string='Code', readonly=True)

@api.multi
def get_code(self):
    count = 0
    reg = "Reg #"
    for record in self:
        count += 1
        record.reg_code = reg + " " + str(count)
        if record.reg_code:
            count += 1
            record.reg_code = reg+" "+str(count)
        else:
            count += 1
            record.reg_code = reg+" "+str(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequence in Odoo.
find sequence in

> Enable Active developer mode
>
> > Settings --> Sequence

[image: Check this]

Then add this code in your module:

change field as

```
reg_code = fields.Char(string='Code',required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, index=True, default= lambda self: self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('student.registration'))
```

Create another xml file like if you want to create sequence by code.

> shipping_sequence.xml

and add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">

        <!-- Sequences for student.registration -->
        <record id="seq_student_registration" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Student Registration</field>
            <field name="code">student.registration</field>
            <field name="prefix">Code-</field>
            <field name="padding">1</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Still reg_code is not saving into database where i can use it for searching purpose.

Comment: This code can help as long as it only save "New" in database.
is it possible to save computed value into database as i mentioned code above because i don't have much idea about sequence in odoo.

Comment: The Best solution is to use sequence , that i have explained in detail above. did you find sequence?

Comment: Please check above

Comment: Then use it. It will help you a lot

Comment: reg_code = fields.Char(string='Code',required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, index=True, default='New')

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
   if vals.get('reg_code ', 'New') == 'New':
       vals['reg_code '] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('student.registration') or 'New'
  #add your class name
   result = super(CLassName, self).create(vals)
   return result


Above code only save 'New' instead of incremental code in database as i define in sequence e.g prefix (code-00) and padding =1, supposed to  be incremented by 1

Comment: share your function here.

Comment: just create sequence like in above picture and replace  your class name with CLassName in super(CLassName),self.create(vals)

Comment: here is code ...
reg_code = fields.Char(string='code', required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, index=True, default='New')

@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('reg_code ', 'New') == 'New':
            vals['reg_code '] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('student.registration') or 'New'
            
        result = super(StudentRegistration, self).create(vals)
        return result

Comment: It works fine for me. Looks like your sequence creation have errors. after giving prefix you can set sequence size(padding) and next number as 1 will give you 1 at start. Check above

Comment: i have created sequence by code 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data noupdate="1">
    <record id="seq_code" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">Student Registration</field>
        <field name="code">student.registration</field>
        <field name="prefix">reg#</field>
        <field name="padding">1</field>
    </record>
</data>
</odoo>

Comment: I am using sequence method to store data but i am unable to store.


reg_code = fields.Char(string='Code',required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, index=True, default='New')

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
   if vals.get('reg_code ', 'New') == 'New':
       vals['reg_code '] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('student.registration') or 'New'
  #add your class name
   result = super(StudentRegistration, self).create(vals)
   return result


The above code with Text field reg_code only storing default value   default="New" , what changes should i need ?

Comment: check above . lets try another method.

Comment: reg_code = fields.Char(string='Code',required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, index=True, default= lambda self: self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('student.registration'))


Now finally this code is working for me ,

Comment: Issue Solved? any other requirement?